# Same-side facing quotation marks

Tags: quotation

I'm creating a story on MiKTeX but when I want to use quotation marks for speech of characters, they face the same side. For example, when I input

```
He hollered, 'Who goes there?'
```

The output is given as

[image]

Notice that the quotation marks are facing the same side. How do I correct this?

Comment: Use a grave accent for the left side.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (La)TeX source, the left and right quotation marks are not self-implementing (as Word tries to do).  Rather, one uses the grave accent (` or ``) for left quotes and the regular apostrophe (' or '') for right quotes.

The use of the double quote character (") will generally be (internally) converted to two single apostrophes ('') by LaTeX.

Thus for the OP's example, `He hollered, 'Who goes there?'`, the quote before `Who` should be replaced with a grave accent in your source document.